# How can I pass a double into a function which takes a null terminated character string in C?

Tags: c, system-calls

I have a `double` and I need to pass it into the [write](http://codewiki.wikidot.com/c:system-calls:write) system call in c.

The write function prototype is `size_t write(int fildes, const void *buf, size_t nbytes);` and the double needs to be passed as the `buf` parameter. The documentation says `buf` is

> A null terminated character string of the content to write.

I have tried to cast it as a `char` pointer like this

```
double my_double = 4.5789; 
char * buf = (char *)&my_double;
```

But I don't know how to add the null character to the end of this.

How can I format this double to be entered into the `write` function?

Edit: I believe someone has updated the documentation I linked to since I asked this question.

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/3/write is a better documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation of `write()` cannot possibly be saying that `buf` is a null terminated character string. You must be looking at the wrong documentation. `buf` is a pointer to an untyped buffer, which is not terminated by anything, its length is specified by `nbytes`.  So, would you like to show us where you found that documentation?

In the mean time, I would suggest that you ignore that documentation, and do the following, which should work:

```
size_t n = write( yourfile, &my_double, sizeof(my_double) );
ASSERT( n == sizeof(my_double) );
```

Comment: This was the documentation that I was looking at http://codewiki.wikidot.com/c:system-calls:write, it's the first result when you google "write function c"... okay either I'm going crazy or someone just updated this documentation after reading my question. The box that says `A pointer to a buffer of at least nbytes bytes, which will be written to the file.` used to say `A null terminated character string of the content to write.`

Comment: LOL yes, you can see mch's edit under "Recent Changes". What can I say, "don't believe everything you read on the internet!"   C-:=

Comment: huh. http://codewiki.wikidot.com/c:system-calls:close size_t filedesc = open("testfile.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT); this webiste looks like a bad practical joke. also the edited write page is still beyond terrible.